# wordpress wp-ecommerce shopping cart header/cookie issue

Tags: php, session, cookies, wordpress

So i have this site here http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com and when you first goto the site you will notice that the top right is blank, if you refresh the page the shopping cart appears in the top right corner.

I believe the reason why it doesnt show up when you first goto the site is because a cookie is not set or something.

If I delete cookie name `PHPSESSID` with the value `fd9lshsp92opvo9aotvoljajj0` (value changes everytime you delete the cookie and create a new one) the shopping cart in the top right corner disappears again.

It seems like the cookie is not being properly...but then again I dont know much about cookies.

How would I set this cookie properly?

I have not idea where `PHPSESSID`is set in wordpress, so I cant find the code for it...but here is the code for the shopping cart, not sure if it will do any good.

`<div style="float:right;" class="taranShoppingCart"><?php echo wpsc_shopping_cart(); ?></div>`

which spits out....

```
<div class="shoppingcart">
<table style="color:#F69F8E;">
<tfoot>
<tr class="cart-widget-total">
<td class="cart-widget-count" style="text-align:right; padding-right:25px; padding-bottom:5px;" colspan="3">
<a href="?page_id=15">Shopping Bag  6 item(s)</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right:15px;">
<a href="?page_id=15">Hello admin</a>
</td>
<td style="padding-right:15px;">
<a href="http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=f26aa87ea3">Logout</a>
</td>
<td>
<div class="live_search_form">
<form class="product_search" action="http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/?page_id=14/" method="GET" style="font-size:0px !important;">
<input id="wpsc_search_autocomplete" class="wpsc_product_search wpsc_live_search_embed .wpsc_live_search" style="padding:0px !important; height:25px !important; vertical-align:top;" autocomplete="off" name="product_search">
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery('#wpsc_search_autocomplete').keypress( function(e){
if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
var url = 'http://www.taranmarlowjewelry.com/?page_id=14'+'?product_search='+jQuery(this).val();
url = encodeURI(url);
jQuery(window.location).attr('href', url);
}
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
<input id="button" class="searchBtn" type="submit" value="GO" name="button">
</form>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Any help would greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Post it on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I did start writing this as a comment but it got lengthy, so here we go:

What's probably happening is when the user first hits your website the session gets initialised and the cookie created. However the cookie will not be obtained until the refresh as it gets passed with the headers (might be wrong here but I think that's how cookies work). So basically on the first request its not present.

What your code needs to do is catch when the cookie is not present and pass through whatever data it stores in the cookie to whatever triggers the basket display. Then once the cookie is present it can just read the cookie.

As I mentioned I'm not totally sure on the Cookie headers thing, so if someone could confirm when Cookie information is loaded that would be helpful.

Comment: How would I go about doing that in Wordpress? Any ideas?

Comment: I will assume that you're using a plugin for the shopping cart, so your options are either find a different plugin which works as you want, or go through the plugin code and find where this session info is generated and fix it.

Comment: This answer appears totally logical as cookie information is not sent on the first pass, but will be on the second. If the case, the solution would be to check the shopping cart code.